# Why does $\prod^n_{j=1}\sigma^{(j)}_x$ commute with this adiabatic Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, quantum-information, quantum-spin

In the section 4.1 of [Quantum Computation by Adiabatic Evolution](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0001106v1.pdf), Farhi et al proposes a quantum adiabatic algorithm to solve the $2$-SAT problem on a ring.

The adiabatic Hamiltonian is defined as 
$$
\tilde{H} (s) = (1-s) \sum^n_{j=1}(1-\sigma^{(j)}_x) + s \sum^n_{j=1}\frac{1}{2} (1-\sigma^{(j)}_z \sigma^{(j+1)}_z )
$$

To prove the correctness of the algorithm, the authors consider an operator which negates the value of the bits.
$$
G = \prod^n_{j=1}\sigma^{(j)}_x
$$

Then on page 13, it is mentioned that $[G, \tilde{H}(s)] = 0$.

**My question:**

How do I prove that $\left[\prod^n_{j=1}\sigma^{(j)}_x, \left((1-s) \sum^n_{j=1}(1-\sigma^{(j)}_x) + s \sum^n_{j=1}\frac{1}{2} (1-\sigma^{(j)}_z \sigma^{(j+1)}_z )\right)\right] = 0$?

Comment: Hello. If you can, please explain what the indexes j, mean. Thanks.

Comment: @ConstantineBlack, $j$ is the index of the qubit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first term (sum) in $\bar H$ obviously commutes with all $\sigma_x$ variables because it's a function of $\sigma_x$ only and they commute with each other.

The second term (sum) in $\bar H$ also commutes with the product of all $\sigma_x$ because the first term in the summand is a $c$-number and the second term $\sigma_z^j \sigma_z^{j+1}$ anticommutes both with $\sigma_x^j$ and $\sigma_x^{j+1}$ (because $\sigma_x,\sigma_z$ anticommute), and it therefore commutes with the product of two $\sigma_x$ (two minus signs give  a plus).